# PHP APC Cache for PHP 5.4.22 Win 7

Tags: php, apc

I need to install APC cache for

Windows 7
Php 5.4.22

can anyone provide me with a binary ? or instructions on how to build one for windows for the specific version of PHP

I see there are binaries available for PHP 5.4.6,5.4.7 etc but not able to find one for 5.4.22

i tried the binaries for 5.4.6 and 5.4.7 but I runtime errors saying that the server stopped working due to an error in the apc.dll.

There is no specific error message

Comment: Can you not update your PHP install to 5.4.6 or 5.4.7?

Comment: I might eventually do that, but was wondering if there was one available for 5.4.22

Comment: If you decide on updating, skip all the way to 5.5 as it has a built-in OPcache!

Answer (score 0):

How to install: http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Installing_APC_in_Windows

Download locations:
http://dev.freshsite.pl/nc/php-accelerators/apc/download/

but first you should check what PHP you have installed (You can find it in phpinfo();):
PHP 5.4.6 
PHP 5.4.6 VC9
PHP 5.4.6 nts
PHP 5.4.6 VC9 nts